# Long into to string - is StrToInt() safe?

Tags: delphi

I have a long int which represents a Unxi timestamp and want to use a string representation of it.

Using IntToStr() works, but worries me because it doesn't say `long`.  Maybe I should use sprintf() instead?

Comment: i think you are using C++ builder instead of delphi :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you meant IntToStr() rather than StrToInt(), and it appears to be overloaded and therefore safe. For the other way around there is StrToInt64().

[Delphi Basics : IntToStr command](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=IntToStr)

Comment: Heh, maybe that was copied and pasted from something else and the author forgot to change it. It is labeled as a function within the page itself.